# How should I edit posts to receive upvotes?

Tags: discussion, support, low-quality-posts, moderation, bad-questions

I'm writing my questions on Stack Overflow my account. I'd edited my bad posts many times. But, people gave a downvote every time, and there is no upvote. My account has been banned for the past last 6 months from posting new questions. I was a fresher, but now I respect the Stack Overflow community. I've tried to vote for my bad posts and got a suspension for one month.

How should I edit posts to receive upvotes?

Comment: Simply you MUST NOT edit to receive upvotes, you should edit bad posts to make them better just for future readers, not for you.

Comment: "I've tried to vote for my bad posts" That is vote fraud.

Comment: @RobertLongson, Not a duplicate, I have been visiting for 155 consecutive days on Stackoverflow to post new queries. I've read and vote for posts. But, this is duplicate problem again? I want to ask through this post _why people are doing such irritating behavior?_
Should I leave Stack Overflow forever?

Comment: I read some your questions and to me they seem too broad. On asking broad questions on Stack Overflow: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." ([Don't Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)) If you still want to be able ask such questions, then Stack Overflow may indeed not be the best site for you.

Comment: @RadLexus, If you are leaving Stack Overflow, then I will also leave. _Why people are always suggesting, this site is not best suited for you to Computer Science student?_

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay I have no idea why posters do not spend some little time searching before posting on SO and getting slammed for duplicating.  It is, indeed, irritating to continually see the same questions, over and over again, week after week:(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From clicking through a couple of your questions, your average question appears to be in this format:

> [Homework definition here]
>
> ---
>
> [Some attempt to make the homework here]
>
> ---
>
> > But I don't understand it, can you please explain it?

The point with Stack Overflow is that it doesn't exist for askers to get a quick answer to their acute problem. When that happens, it's just a side-effect.

The site is meant to become a collection of high-quality questions and answers.

It's just that your homework questions are very unlikely to help future visitors. For your eventual next questions, try to phrase the questions differently (don't copy the homework assignment verbatim) and share your actual *research towards the subject*, not your suspicions to what the answer should be.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: Although the OP rejects their question being a duplicate [the guidance in here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/578411) is still relevant.

Comment: @rene yeah, but in contrast to the main site, I don't really care about people on meta asking for feedback specific to them, as opposed to a generic wall of text that may or may not apply to them. It's not like meta has enough drama already.